# Dismiss Alert - Global setting

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Is there any option to set dismiss alert as Global variable.

Assume alert may appear between tests in IE,this may not appear in
firefox.Now instead of having accept alert in all code ,if we have
global option ,i will set dismiss alert and run.Selenium native code
will have idea of alert and dismiss it.

Is there any other option available?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option available. You can try one of the following:

Override `window.alert(string message)` method with something more appropriate. Like an empty method.

Edit your methods so that they always invoke:

```
try {
    driver.switchTo().alert().doSomething();
} catch (NoAlertPresentException ignored) {
    // nothing to do
}
```

or maybe place this in the relevant pieces of code:

```
if (driver instanceof InternetExplorerDriver) {
    driver.switchTo().alert().doSomething();
}
```

or use good old [Selenium RC](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) for some of those yet impossible tasks: [here's how](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#answerOnNextPrompt%28java.lang.String%29) ... or [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation%28%29). You can use `driver` and `selenium` commands almost interchangeably throughout the test.

Comment: Yes.But ,Checking whether the alert is present is waste of
time. It will be good if web driver itself has this feature in build.